# Android, change the profile of the phone

Tags: android, vibration, plane

I would like to change the profile of the phone, for instance change from vibrator mode to normal mode or even plane mode. I cannot find in the permission list anything to allow this type of change. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It is done using [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html). Refer the developers guide and it will help you a certain extent.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but did you look at android.permission.VIBRATE ?

Comment: No, I think VIBRATE only allow developer to make the mobile vibrating. I want to change the behaviour of the phone when it receive call/text message etc.. so that it will ring or vibrate or do nothing.